# Flutlab.io "package:flutter/material.dart" not importing so FlatButton widget not working

Tags: flutter, dart, import, widget

Using the online IDE Flutlab.io, I wanted to create a FlatButton widget so I imported "package:flutter/material.dart" in my main.dart file but when I run my code it says that the method FlatButton is not defined for my project. How do I fix this?

I imported that statement but got an error.

Comment: Please add a code snippet

Comment: FlatButton is deprecated, you will need to use TextButton instead. Please read official flutter documentaion to stay updated: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons